# How to create a User delegation SAS key for Azure Blob access using old Microsoft.WindowsAzure .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to access azure blob for file uploads from .NET. I want to use user delegation SAS token here since they are considered secure. I can find many documentation for the .NET 12 library which uses the Azure.Identity and Azure.Storage namespaces.

But the project I'm working on does not has this libraries available, it has the Microsoft.WindowsAzure namespace available since it is an older .NET azure SDK. Now I cannot update to the latest versions so I am stuck with the older SDK and am unable to find documentation for accessing blobs using SAS in older SDK. I tried to see the new classes and find similar ones in the older SDK but many methods/classes are missing or different.

If you have any reference or resource on how to use the Microsoft.WindowsAzure older SDK to access blob content using user delegated SAS key, plese share. Currently we use the storage access key for blob acccess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in your question, [Get user delegation SAS key is now not support in 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure'.](https://docs.azure.cn/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient?view=azure-dotnet#methods) There is no such method in 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure'.

But, you can send request manually to get the SAS key, you need this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-user-delegation-key